# Template loading in Django 1.4

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to follow best practice with template loading and settings.py. The advice I've seen pre-dates 1.4, hence I've added `'..'` to the code below to compensate for 1.4's apparently more nested project structure:

```
import os
DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    os.path.join(DIR, '..', 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

It seems to work, but is this what I'm meant to be doing?

Since you're supposed to use forward slashes all the time, are we not as well to do `DIR + '/../templates'.replace('\\','/'),` -instead of the call to `join()`?

Another newbie question is: why not use only the `app_directories` template loader, and so not have to worry about absolute paths?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I have it on settings.py:

```
#settings.py
from os.path import dirname, join, realpath
# have in mind that I have settings.py under project_root/project/settings.py
# so you probably want to check your path to your project root folder first
ROOT_DIR = realpath(join(dirname(__file__), '..'))
MEDIA_ROOT = realpath(join(ROOT_DIR, 'media'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `posixpath.join` to get `/` as the path delimiter, no matter on which platform the code runs. See the documentation of [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Comment: not sure if that would work as I assume my `DIR` variable is defined in a platform-specific way

Answer (score 0):

About your first question:

```
DIR + '/../templates'.replace('\\','/')
```

will replace backslashes in the '/../templates' part, so no, its not the same. Doing

```
DIR.replace('\\','/') + '/../templates'
```

would indeed be the same, but os.path.join is a more elegant and clean approach.

About your second question, there might be occassions where you just want to override templates. Say, for example that you only use 3rd-party django applications and you only want to override a template in one of these applications. Since django searches for templates in the order your TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting dictates (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types), you could set your TEMPLATE_LOADERS as follows:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

and your TEMPLATE_DIRS exactly like you said:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(DIR, '..', 'mytemplates').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

Then if you place a template inside the 'mytemplates' directory it will be matched before the equivalent app_directories template is found (remember filesystem loader comes before the app_directories loader). Therefore django will use your version instead of the original.

It is a matter of design after all: You could implement a custom application and override the template, but again applications should perform certain task(s) and stuffing irrelevant templates in the 'templates' folder does not feel right.

Answer (score 0):

The way i have it,

settings.py:

```
import os.path
static = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
media = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media')
template= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'template')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    template,
)
# rest is the same
```

Then make a folder called 'static', 'media', 'template' in `myproject.myproject`

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to organize the project is to follow [LINK1](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BestPracticesToWorkWith3rdPartyAppsAndMakingYoursPortable) or [LINK2](http://blog.zacharyvoase.com/2010/02/03/django-project-conventions/) instead of following default directory structure in Django 1.4. Django structure is not intuitive when you have many apps including 3rd party apps.

Based on the structure in the links I am doing the following for template loading:

```
#settings.py
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

PROJ_ROOT = dirname(abspath(__file__))
APPS_ROOT = join(PROJ_ROOT, 'apps')

sys.path.append(join(PROJ_ROOT,'apps'))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(APPS_ROOT, 'templates'),
    join(PROJ_ROOT, 'templates'),
)
```

Also, it will be useful to put app specific templates in ../app_name/templates/app_name/ to avoid template name conflicts.